# SQL syntax increased efficiency

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssrs-2008

I have an SQL query which uses a similar piece of code as below numerous times (around 50 times)

This is causing the query to run slowly. Im looking for a more efficient way of coding this query.

```
 AND ((table1.field1 <=(dbo.view1.field2) OR table1.field1 IS NULL )
```

All the fields im concerned with are dates.

Comment: is this script running in a stored procedure ?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
AND (ISNULL(table1.field1, dbo.view1.field2) <= dbo.view1.field2)
```

Answer (score 1):

By looking in your given snippet, I cannot tell exactly the efficiency of the condition in the query. But I'll advise you to create an `Index` on the fields used in joining tables and the fields used in conditions.

Answer (score 1):

With the amount of code you supplied, it's hard to guess where the bottleneck is. But avoid calculation comparisons and isolate the indexed columns. The more index records that can fit in a block of memory, the faster your query will run.

Answer (score 0):

```
AND (table1.field1 IS NULL OR (table1.field1 <=(dbo.view1.field2))
```

You should xreate some indexes depending on your queryes.

Answer (score 0):

You should really take a look at the SQL Execution Plan, this will give you a visualization of what is going on with the query and where it is taking the most time.  Generally the server will be able to optimize your query in the first place, so rearranging your `WHERE` statement is unlikely to make a difference.

See [this post](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/) to get you started on the basics.

Answer (score 0):

Add indexes for both columns if you can afford it.